# Set Curve Radius of **Realized Instances** by Spline ID

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, geometry, splines, random

I have a series of Splines (10 in the below example), created by **realizing the instances** generated by an Instance on Points node:

[image]

[image]

I am attempting to randomize the radius of these Splines.
If I combine a Random Value node with a Set Radius node, the individual points of each Spline receive a random radius. I haven't been able to find a way to apply the **same** random value to each point in a Spline (but a different random value per Spline).

[image]

[image]

This is the effect I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Please note, this problem is part of a larger node tree.
For reasons that are not worth explaining, it is necessary for me to realize the instances. I also do not have the option to, for example, convert the curves to mesh **before** instancing, and affect the radius of the mesh using the Scale inputs on the Instance on Points node.

I'm trying to find a way to randomize the radius of these curves **after** realizing the instances, and **before** converting to mesh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

[image]

[image]

but one request for the future: if you do have the node tree and the blend file anyway, PLEASE do provide the blend file in the question so we don't have to rebuild everything. I am pretty sure you will attract more people (especially the lazy ones like me) for your questions. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer and noted for the future, I will include my .blend file.

Comment: You are welcome